# $E[X|X>c]$ = $\frac{\phi(c)}{1-\Phi(c)}$ , given X is $N(0,1)$ , how to derive this?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

I came across this useful formula that , if $X$ is distributed as a standard normal , then $E[X\mid X>c]$ = $\frac{\phi(c)}{1-\Phi(c)}$. Where $\phi(x)$ is the probability density function of the standards normal  and $\Phi(c)$ is the cdf of the standard normal. I was wondering how to derive this formula.

I thought
$$E[X\mid X>c]= \frac { \int_{c}^{\infty} x f_X(x) dx }{1-\Phi(c)}$$
so how to get the formula $\frac{\phi(c)}{1-\Phi(c)}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there, now just observe that since
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\phi(x)=-x\phi(x)$$
it follows that
$$ \int_{c}^{\infty}x\phi(x)\;dx=-\phi(x)\Big|_{c}^{\infty}=\phi(c)$$

Comment: I was wondering if similar kind of expression can be derived for $var[X|X>c]$ for which I would have to derive a formula for  $E[X^2|X>c]$ , I know $E[X^2|X>C]$ = $ \frac{\int_{c}^{\inf} x^2 f_X(x) dx}{1- \Phi(c)}$ , any clues how to simplify this in a similar way ?

Comment: I suggest using integration by parts to evaluate $\int_{c}^{\infty}x^2\phi(x)\;dx$.